# ProForm forms stopped submitting, no errors

Tags: forms

I've already emailed the plugin dev about this, but I need to get this working again as soon as possible.

I have some forms created using ProForms that have been working fine. Today I noticed none of them are submitting. When the submit button is pressed it refreshes the page, the form fields are empty, and my "success" message doesn't display. The submission doesn't appear in the control panel like it should. I don't receive any errors. I haven't changed the templates at all. Yesterday I added some new fields to one of the forms, but had not tested it yet so I don't know if this did something.

I know I don't have too many details, but if someone is familiar with this plugin and might be able to take a look that would be great. We need to fix this urgently, so if you can help out we could throw some bucks your way. Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you could add some more details which will help us help you - such as minimal template code, what versions you are on, whether you have run any updates lately, what you have tried so far etc. Try reverting your changes and see whether it fixes it. Try to create a minimum possible template which recreates the error and copy it here. Try a different browser (to rule out cookies/auth issues).

Comment: Please remember to mark your answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkbox to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start troubleshooting by removing the new fields that you added yesterday and reverting back to the old template version if you made template changes.

Are you seeing any JS errors in your console?

Any CSS/HTML issues in validation reports that might be causing issues?

Also, check your PHP error logs on the actual server.

Were there any server changes?

Did you make any other changes to templates, addons etc yesterday?

Clear browser cache and cookies.

Comment: What's the URL where we can see this form?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the support MediaGirl and Adrian. The developer helped me out and it turns out it was something I did the other day that messed it up. I was having a different problem with one of my extremely large forms loading slowly. I turned on caching for that template. It didn't do anything (and was the wrong thing to do), and I forgot to turn it off. Once Isaac noticed this I turned it off and everything was ok. Thansk again!